# Require_once in class files

Tags: object-oriented, php

I have a big system of classes and objects which rely on each other in order to function. Should I put all of the `require_once()` calls for dependencies at the top of each class file? ie:

```
<?php
    require_once( 'neededClass.php' );

    class MainClass{
        $this->neededClass = new neededClass();
    }
?>
```

Or should I make a big list of all my classes and include them at the base script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each file should require all its *direct* dependencies. If A calls B and C, then A requires both B and C, even if B also requires C. This keeps A from breaking if a new version of B does not require C.

Comment: Yep this is exactly how I landed on it. Nice to hear my brain is still making sense!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to have PHP require files on demand. If you're already using Composer to load third party libraries, you can simply add your own [autoloading configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) to the composer.json file.

Comment: Yeah since digging deeper I have seen that it makes a lot more sense to use namespaces and autoloading - thanks!